# Where we need to enter the mysql details for dbunit testing

Tags: php, unit-testing

I followed this link http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/database.html there i found some useful details of php db unit testing.But i have one doubt .Where we need to enter the mysql configuration details Any Idea

The code is like this

> require_once "PHPUnit/Extensions/Database/TestCase.php";
>
> class MyGuestbookTest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase {
>
> ```
> public function getConnection()
> {
>     $pdo = new PDO('sqlite::memory:');
>     return $this->createDefaultDBConnection($pdo, ':memory:');
> }
>
> public function getDataSet()
> {
>     return
> ```
>
> $this->createFlatXMLDataSet(dirname(**FILE**).'/_files/guestbook-seed.xml');
>       } }

I am using MySQL.Can any one answer me for this where i need to enter the mysql username password and database name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb', 'root', '');
return $this->createDefaultDBConnection($pdo, 'testdb');
```

Comment: ok thanks for reply.How we can check wheather the connection is ok or not?

Comment: you can find all info you need here : http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/database.html

Comment: i am referring that thing.But i cant understand since i am new to this testing.One more help how we can get data from the database using this .I need to return all the data from a table inside that database.please reply

Comment: $queryTable = $this->getConnection()->createQueryTable(
    'example', 'SELECT id, name FROM example'
);